# How to manage a large buffer in java? GC overhead limit exceeded

Tags: java, xml, garbage-collection, buffer

I try to parse a 2GB XML file with SAXParser. My task is about information retrieval and I'm told to handle the information I need in memory. The file is separated into documents which consist of words. Each word is an object in which its appearance in other documents should be stored.

When the next document starts I pop all these objects an put them into a perfect sized array, to be as memory efficient as possible. NOW THE PROBLEM: This method creates too many temporary objects, so the garbage collector does too much work. Is there a way to avoid creating that many temporary objects or to make the buffer not collide with the GC?

```
public class Stack<T> {
StackObject<T>  top;
boolean empty;
int entryCounter;
Stack(){
    empty = false;
}   
public void init(T obj){
    top = new StackObject<T>(obj);
}
public T pop(){ 
    T tmp = top.self;
    if(top.next != null){
        top.self = null;
        top = top.next;
    }
    else{
        empty = true;
    }
    return tmp;
}
public void push(T obj){
    StackObject<T> tmp = new StackObject<T>(obj);
    tmp.next = top;
    top = tmp;
    entryCounter += 1;
    if(tmp.next == tmp){
        System.out.println("ERROR");
    }
}
}

class StackObject<T>{
T self = null;
StackObject<T> next = null;
StackObject(T obj){
    self = obj;
}
}
```

Comment: This is pretty unclear - you're basically trying to describe some code, and then asking us how to make it more efficient.  What are these temporary objects?

Comment: I've edited the request.

Comment: Simply store an array `T[] elements` in `Stack` would be easier; then increase its length by a multiplicative amount when you run out of space. There's no need for the instances of the `StackObject` class.

Comment: The GC overhead limit means you have too little free memory.  The simplest thing to do is to increase your maximum heap size.

Comment: The problem is, that the size of the array is variable by some thousand entries. Using Arraylist for example turned out to be way too slow since the resizing takes too much time. And I already increased the heapsize to 2 gigabyte.

Comment: Why are you implementing your own Stack class? And you don't need the `self` member, but you do need some other member of type T for stack object to refer to. This is not working code.

Comment: Please don't use terms like "large" and "huge" which mean completely different things to different people. Give us some numbers, even if they are only approximate.

Comment: have you considered presizing the arraylist?

Comment: If you're being told to handle information arising out of a 2GB file in memory you are already being misdirected, and micro-optimizing by implementing your own stack class isn't actually going to get you anywhere. Your problem is not time but space. What do you have to actually do with this information?

Comment: The XML is a collection of documents and I shall find similarities between those, by analysing the words which occur in the text. So for each (about 4000) document I save the words and for each word I save the document in which it occurs. After that I want to use different operations to determin similarity, but that's another question.

Comment: The number of Strings in your array will exceed the number of objects created by this redundant Stack implementation by orders of magnitude, so the number of those objects is not likely to cause a GC problem. Resizing underlying arrays by the `Stack` class is not a major overhead in the first place. So this code does not account for the problem you describe and is not adequately motivated. I don't even see why it should be a stack as opposed to say a `HashSet`: there is nothing stack-like about the problem you've described. You're barking up the wrong tree altogether.

Answer (score 0):

Your `Stack` class is inefficient in its use of memory.  It will use about 4 times as much memory per stack entry than (say) an `ArrayList`.

You say this:

> Using Arraylist for example turned out to be way too slow since the resizing takes too much time.

One way to solve that is to implement an array-based stack that doubles the size of the backing array when it resizes.  If you use this policy for resizing, then `N` pushed to an empty stack will give between `N` and `2N` extra copies due to resizing.

At any rate, while you might be saving CPU on resizing, the flip side is that your current implementation loses a lot of that gain in the overheads of constructing many `StackObject` instances, and the indirect costs of garbage collection, poor locality, and increased memory footprint.

Comment: `ArrayList` already uses exponential sizing, which is what makes its insert operations amortized O(1) in the first place

Comment: I am aware of that.  But the growth policy is `new_size = current_size + 50%`.

Comment: The difference between 1.5N vs. 2N or unlikely to make or break it.

Comment: Actually, it is quite significant in terms of the number of times the elements are copied.  And since the OP was complaining that resizing was slow, it is worth looking into.  (Of course, the OP could be incorrect.  He doesn't say if he profiled the code to see if resizing is really a significant cost.)